# AttributeError: module 'torchtext.data' has no attribute 'Field'

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to run a git [project](https://github.com/fastnlp/style-transformer) used pytorch and torchtext but when I run it, it raise error:

```
  File "main.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 50, in main
    train_iters, dev_iters, test_iters, vocab = load_dataset(config)
  File "/home/esmailza/style transfer/style-transformer/data.py", line 23, in load_dataset
    TEXT = data.Field(batch_first=True, eos_token='<eos>')
AttributeError: module 'torchtext.data' has no attribute 'Field'
```

torch version  = 1.8.0
torchtext version = 0.9

```
def load_dataset(config, train_pos='train.pos', train_neg='train.neg',
                 dev_pos='dev.pos', dev_neg='dev.neg',
                 test_pos='test.pos', test_neg='test.neg'):

    root = config.data_path
    TEXT = data.Field(batch_first=True, eos_token='<eos>')
    
    dataset_fn = lambda name: data.TabularDataset(
        path=root + name,
        format='tsv',
        fields=[('text', TEXT)]
    )
```

Comment: Is this an issue in BucketIterator?

Comment: @OctopuSS7 yes, actually the error raise when he defines Field, but the field is gonna used in BucketIterator.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From TorchText `0.9.0` [Release Notes](https://github.com/pytorch/text/releases/tag/v0.9.0-rc5)

> `torchtext.data.Field` -> `torchtext.legacy.data.Field`
> This means, all features are still available, but within `torchtext.legacy` instead of `torchtext`.

`torchtext.data.Field` has been moved to `torchtext.legacy.data.Field`

And the imports would change this way:

```
from torchtext.legacy import data
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, @Rishabh Kumar answer as well, this works for me!

> From TorchText 0.9.0 Release Notes

Based on v0.9 release https://github.com/pytorch/text/releases/tag/v0.9.0-rc5

The current users of the legacy code will experience BC breakage as we have retired the legacy code (#1172, #1181, #1183). The legacy components are placed in torchtext.legacy.data folder as follows:

```py
torchtext.data.Pipeline -> torchtext.legacy.data.Pipeline
torchtext.data.Batch -> torchtext.legacy.data.Batch
torchtext.data.Example -> torchtext.legacy.data.Example
torchtext.data.Field -> torchtext.legacy.data.Field
torchtext.data.Iterator -> torchtext.legacy.data.Iterator
torchtext.data.Dataset -> torchtext.legacy.data.Dataset
```

This means, all features are still available, but within torchtext.legacy instead of torchtext.

Answer (score 1):

use torchtext with version 0.6
`pip install torchtext==0.6.0`  and
Restart your kernel

Comment: Thank you, this version supports torchtext.data.Field