# Module "torchtext.data" has no attribute "Field"

Tags: python, nlp, torch, torchtext

I am trying to define a vocabulary with PyTorch to later input my dataset into a Neural Network. This would be the first step to create a dataset.

This is the code I am using:

```
text_field = torchtext.data.Field(tokenize="spacy")
text_field.build_vocab(train_data.Text, min_freq=3)
```

By running the code, I get the following error: "module 'torchtext.data' has no attribute 'Field'"
I already looked at solutions where they suggest to use "torchtext.legacy.data.Field" instead, but nothing seems to work. I am using Python 3.10.1 and torchtext 0.15.1.
Does anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: The question seems to be duplicated with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66516388/attributeerror-module-torchtext-data-has-no-attribute-field)

Answer (score 0):

i am afraid you have to downgrade pytorch and torchtext versions, that's what i did in order to work with data.field